# CLS-Compliant issue

Tags: vb.net, cls-compliant

I have the following property defined.  MyLibrary.PumpSignal is an enum as follows:

```
Public Enum PumpSignal As Integer
    PumpOff = 0
    PumpOn = 1
End Enum
```

Then I have another class with a property of the PumpSignal type.

```
Property PumpState() As MyLibrary.PumpSignal
        Get
            Return m_PumpState
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As MyLibrary.PumpSignal)
            m_PumpState = value
        End Set
End Property
```

.NET keeps complaining that the Return value from PumpState is no cls-compliant.

Comment: No repro.  Quote the *exact* error message you see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A type is only CLS-compliant if it or its assembly is explicitly marked as CLS-compliant.

Add `<Assembly: CLSCompliant(True)>` to the library.

Alternatively, add `<CLSCompliant(False)>` to the property.